# Why is my curl_init() just dying on me?

Tags: php, apache, twitter, curl, xdebug

I found some PHP code on the 'net that supposedly will help me send some text from my web site to be posted in a twitter feed.

However, it just dies on the curl_init() part. The browser shows an empty page (no HTML content whatsoever), and the code stops executing.

Here is the code:

```
$url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$body");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

I am testing on Ubuntu 11.04, using NetBeans (yes, I know Netbeans is designed for Java debugging, but it's free and has a very good PHP debugging plugin) with xdebug. I'm testing on a local Apache 2.2 server.

I've tried running the debugger to see where it fails, and the debugger also bails when the code hits the curl_init() part. It simply exits the debugger, and the browser, as mentioned above, shows only an empty page.

Is there something I need to configure or do to get curl_init() to actually do stuff?

Comment: Have you checked it curl is available ?

Comment: And try this $curl_handle = curl_init() or die("DIE !! ");

Comment: `php -m | grep curl` the fastest way to check this module, if no, just `apt-get install php5-curl`

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting on?

Comment: Just an aside - isn't Twitter switching to oAuth authentication? Wouldn't this method be rendered obsolete if/when that happens?

Comment: @Lucanos: It seems you're right. And, of course, oAuth is unbelievably complicated. And I thought this would be easy and maybe fun. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the `curl` module is not installed or enabled in your PHP setup. You can check for this in various ways:

- see if [`extension_loaded('curl')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) (as mentioned in that page, you can do the same from the command line with the `php -m` command but *be careful* -- I have see installations where command line PHP was using a different php.ini that the Apache module!)
- see if [`function_exists('curl_init')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)
- check the output of `phpinfo()`
- inspect php.ini

If `curl` is not installed (as it sounds like), install it and your problem is solved.

Comment: Wow... I feel like a moron. I just assumed the curl commands were part of the standard PHP install. I didn't even consider that it would be a separate module. I installed it, and it worked. D'oh! Thanks for setting me straight!